# Which domain should I register for SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, dns, cname

I have a simple website host that gives me a domain like website.com which show the website hosted on that server.

I have a CNAME on website.com that redirects to server.cloudapp.net (Azure Virtual machine running Linux)
server.website.com redirects to server.cloudapp.net.

I need to access the user camera on Chrome, and for that, the website need's SSL.

I can purchase a SSL certificate for website.com, but would it work on my cname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificates subject must include all names you see in the URL in the browser. Thus is you have a CNAME aliasing foo.example.com to bar.example.com than foo.example.com will be the one visible in the URL and you must have the certificate for it.

Note that CNAME is just an alias and not a redirection. With a redirection (i.e. HTTP status codes 30x) the URL would change, while with a CNAME it does not.